# On the best arch types for underground cities

Tags: physics, cities, architecture

I am working on a civilization that often digs into mountains, and I am wondering what form of arch would work best to hold up all the mass from the mountain above the halls. I know many arch types exist, I am just wondering which one is the best at load bearing.

I am also wondering in general how to best deal with the mass of the rock above. But most pertinent question is for the arch.

Comment: This seems like a question that could be solved with a rudimentary amount of basic research. Is there a specific worldbuilding issue you're trying to solve, or are you asking for a list of arches.

Comment: What did Google tell you was the best load-bearing arch?

Comment: What time period are you talking about? Modern age will have a different answer to the middle ages.

Comment: Any elliptical arch will do, from a semicircle/hemisphere to something much taller or wider. The wider you need a chamber or arch to be at the bottom, the narrower the arch needs to be to prevent the middle from collapsing.

Comment: Agree with previous remark, you did not specify. Q: Should your arch span the entire city diameter, or are we only talking halls, roads and tunnels ? An arch e.g. part of a round tunnel will not need to bear the entire weight of the mountain above it.  When your arch would span an entire city, or a very large hall, it would become a different story, it would depend on the size of the mountain *and* the size of your city! Please add the diameter of the building or city to your question.

Comment: Halls and some very large rooms/atriums. In terms of tech it is far future. Need for going inside was mostly due to the planet in question being mostly mountainous.

Answer (score 2):

**No need of arches inside the mountains**

There are many examples where spaces are dug inside the mountains. There are no arches inside. Stone surface holds itself. You need arches if you dig in mud.

**Madain Saleh in Saudi Arabia**

Outside and inside view are shown below.

[image]

**Khewra Salt Mines in Pakistan**

Outside and inside view are shown below. (Picture taken from [here](https://twitter.com/iftikharalipti/status/1164239301422604296?lang=zh-Hant))

[image]

Comment: If the ceiling was higher like 3 or 4 times than the pictures, would you need some arches and pillars?

Comment: Normally ceilings are not dug high because (1) there is no need (2) It takes a lot of power to dig the stone. But in Khewra Salt Mines in Pakistan, in some places, ceilings are more than 4 times high because there are deep brine ponds below. There are pillars but no special type of arches. In some places, arches have been dug in semi-circular or semi-elliptic style. See images of Khewra Salt Mines in Pakistan on Google.

Comment: I would imagine that also depends on the type of rock.

Comment: Yes. First example is for hard stone and second example is for pink Himalayan rock salt. For mud or soft material, you need semi-circular or semi-elliptic arches or wooden planks supported by wooden poles as used in soft coal mines.

Comment: Those are kinda a lot smaller than I imagine. Those are closer to tiny, tiny mountains. I mean more like several kilometres tall.

Comment: @Zoey Khewra Salt Mines are in a big mountain. As told here (https://www.britannica.com/place/Salt-Range) "The range is approximately 186 miles (300 km) long from east to west, and its width, in the central and eastern parts, is from 5 to 19 miles. Its average height is 2,200 feet, and its highest altitude, at Sakesar mountain, is 4,992 feet (1,522 m)". Read this also (https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/khewra-salt-mines).